# implementing Target - Action pattern in custom view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, target-action

I've created a custom view which inherits from NSView.
My goal is to notify my NSWindowControl which is associated with the window that contains the custom view, when the user click the the custom view.

I would like to implement this using the Action - Target pattern , just like a NSButton does.
So that I will be able connect the custom view with an action in the window controller using the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your custom view header file:

```
@interface MyCustomView : NSView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id userClickedTarget;
@property (assign, nonatomic) SEL userClickedAction;

@end
```

Synthesize the getter/setter in the custom view implementation file (this is actually optional with recent versions of Xcode/clang):

```
@synthesize userClickedTarget = _userClickedTarget;
@synthesize userClickedAction = _userClickedAction;
```

and to call the target/action within your code:

```
if (_userClickedTarget && _userClickedAction) {
    [_userClickedTarget performSelector:_userClickedAction
                             withObject:self
                             afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

Note that using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` *decouples* the call from your view code and makes it run the next time the runloop is processed.

Comment: I added the code, yet still in the Interface builder, when I right click the custom view, I can't see the "sent action" section with the selector to connect with the window controller, like there is in NSButton.

Comment: @amramaz You'd have to set that up programmatically, perhaps in the custom view's `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: Is there any way to do it using the IB ? I want it to behave just like the built in cocoa views.

Comment: @amramaz I don't think so, no.